# How to set x-www-form-urlencoded in the REST POST snap of Snaplogic?

Tags: rest, post, paypal, data-integration, snaplogic

I'm trying to create a pipeline which given the client ID and client secret, gets the access token for PayPal. I'm able to do it using Postman but I'm unable to do the same using Snaplogic.

[image: x-www-form-urlencoded]

In the above picture, you can see that I have to set `grant_type` in the `Body` section as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. How can I do this in a REST POST snap?

[image: REST POST snap]

I'm not using the actual screenshot of my pipeline. Instead, I'm using the pic taken from [this](http://doc.snaplogic.com/com-snaplogic-snaps-rest-post_1) documentation which didn't prove useful in my case. Where can I set `grant_type` in the given snap (refer to the pic above)?

**Update:** I'm using a `REST Basic Auth` Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grant_type` should be set as an Query parameter
see the following post:

[snapLogic REST Account for Yahoo OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593773/snaplogic-rest-account-for-yahoo-oauth2)