# snapLogic REST Account for Yahoo OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, logic, yahoo-api, snaplogic

How do you create a snapLogic REST Account for Yahoo OAuth2?

I'm able to get the Request Authorization part to work but after I authrozie the application, snapLogic does not have the Access token populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the settings that I used to successfully establish an OAuth connection with yahoo using the explicit grant flow (https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/)

Depsite the parameters that yahoo outlines in their documentation, the snapLogic REST Account object does not need you to explicitly define all of those parameters. Here are the parameters that I defined to get Authorize and Refresh token to work.

[image: snapLogic REST Account]